# A class of 10 students is divided in two teams. Find the probability of students A and B to be in the same team.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, combinations

My take to this problem is this:

In the case the two teams have the same amount of students. If student A is on team 1 (or 2, it does not matter), then there's 4 slots available for student B. So the probability of B getting that slot is $\frac{4}{9}$. So, the probability of A and B to be in the same team is $\frac{4}{9}$

How do I deal with finding the probability in the case the teams are not even? (2-8, 3-7, 4-6). How can I do this problem using combinations?

Comment: This is not a meaningful question unless you set down how the teams are formed. If the group is split 50/50 at random, then your analysis is correct. If every student is independently assigned to either team with probability $\frac 12$, then the probability that they are in the same team will be $\frac12$ -- but this includes the degenerate situation of all students being on the same team.

Comment: You want to use conditional probabilities. So the probability that student A goes to team 1 times the probability that student 2 goes to team 1 given student 1 went to team 1 plus the probability student 1 went to team 2 times the probability student 2 goes to team 2 given student 1 went to team 2.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that one team of three students is chosen at random from the class. Two given students A and B are in one team if they go to chosen team or if stay at the rest part of $7$ students. The total number of possibilities to choose $3$ students is $\binom{3}{10}=120$, the number of favorable combinations is 
$$
\binom{1}{8}+\binom{3}{8}=8+56=64,
$$
and the probability is $\frac{64}{120}=\frac{8}{15}$.
Here $\binom{1}{8}$ is the number of variants to choose three students with A and B and one extra student chosen from the rest $8$ students. The summand $\binom{3}{8}$ calculates the number of variants to choose $3$ students so that A and B stay in the second team.